# How to make Spring auto-inject user entity in each RequestMapping from Spring Security Authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I'm new to Spring development and I use Spring Security for JWT authentication in my application.

It is already configured and works fine, but the only messy thing is unpacking the Principal in each API request mapping. I only encode the user UUID in a JWT payload, but I need the entire `User` entity fetched from database in each request mapping.

Currently my code looks like:

```java
@GetMapping("/something")
public SomeResponse someMethod(Authentication authentication) {
    CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    MyUserEntity user = userService.findByUuid(userDetails.getUuid());

    // ...
}
```

But I want to create some kind of a middleware so I'll be able to call `findByUuid` before the controller receives the request and then pass the entity to Spring to inject it, so the mapping code will look like:

```java
@GetMapping("/some")
public SomeResponse someMethod(MyUserEntity user) {
    // ...
}
```

I've searched for the same problem and the only idea I found was creating a filter which performs the user lookup by their UUID and setting the request attribute:

```java
@Component
public class UserFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setAttribute("user", new User("Jerry"));
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

And then injecting the `WebRequest` into each mapping:

```java
@GetMapping("/current-user")
public String getCurrentUser(WebRequest request) {
  var user = (User) request.getAttribute("user", WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
  return user.getUsername();
}
```

But it still doesn't look like a good approach as it forces me to repeat the same line for each of my 50 API methods.

Is there a way to manipulate the arguments injected to a request mapping by Spring?

Comment: You can write a `MethodArgumentResolver` and register that with Spring MVC to do what you want. But why isn't your user the same as your `UserDetails` in the first place? Why have 2 different objects? If they are the same you can use the normal `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation to achieve what you want.

Comment: @M.Deinum that's because my user entity is currently a JPA entity with many fields and some relations so I didn't want to mix the objects together and left `UserDetails` implementation for authentication only. I'm going to refactor this to achieve clearer code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M.Deinum, I was able to set up my own `HandlerMethodArgumentsResolver` component which can provide the required argument:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticatedUserArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(@NonNull MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(MyUserEntity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(@NonNull MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, @NonNull NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

        return userService.findByUuid(userDetails.getUuid());
    }
}
```

And use it as expected:

```java
@GetMapping("/some")
public SomeResponse someMethod(MyUserEntity user) {
    // ...
}
```